# How to feed client request headers and server response headers in aiohttp server response body?

Tags: python, http, head, aiohttp

A simple `aiohttp` server code below, I want to know how to return all client's http request head information and server response http head info in server's response.

A simple target is when I use web browser open the http://127.0.0.1:8080, the web page can display client's http request head and server response http head immediately.

Any help is appreciated.

```
from aiohttp import web

async def handle(request):

    request_head = web.Request.headers          //Q1?
    response_head = web.Response.headers        //Q2?

    return web.Response("\n".join((request_head,response_head)))

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', handle)

web.run_app(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

managed got a dirty solution with flaw regarding the response head part - not very sure the 2nd web.Response will change the header itself, any improvement is appreciated, thanks.

```
from aiohttp import web


async def handle(request):

    request_head = tuple((k.encode('utf-8'), v.encode('utf-8')) for k, v in request.headers.items())

    resp = web.Response(text = str(request_head))
    response_head = tuple((k.encode('utf-8'), v.encode('utf-8')) for k, v in resp.headers.items())

    resp = web.Response(text = "\n".join((str(request_head),str(response_head))))

    return resp

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', handle)
web.run_app(app)
```